# Rails multiple separate dropdown fields for has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models associated with has_and_belongs_to_many

```
# post.rb    
class Post < ApplicationRecord
      has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords
```

I know that in `views/posts/_form.html.erb` I could do something like

```
form.select(:keyword_ids, Keyword.all.collect {|k| [ k.name, p.id ] }, multiple: true)
```

So then I would get one multi-select dropdown.

What if I want to have each keyword_id in a separate drop-down menu (not combined in one) and have all the keyword_ids from the separate dropdowns collected in one array when the form is submitted?

I tried solving it with `fields_for` and `accepts_attributes_for` but in that case, when updating the model the id that's sent from the form to the controller is always fixed to the ones of the keywords that the model had initially and it seems like it cannot be changed which makes sense since I understand this function is only supposed to change attributes of children, not change the child itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the view

```
 # views/posts/_form.html/erb
 <% @post.keywords.each do |keyword| %>
    <%= select_tag "post[keyword_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(Keyword.all, "id", "name", keyword.id) %>
 <% end %>
```

Adding `keyword.id` in the `options_from_collection_for_select` will set the default value to the existing value if the model is updated.

In the controller

```
# post_controller.rb
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit({ keyword_ids: [] })
  end
```